# replace all the n occurences in a list per a given list - ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

example  `remplace_par_liste 2 [-4;-5] [1;2;3;2;2;9] --> [1;-4;-5;3;-4;-5-4;-5;9]`

I know how to do it with an occurence but not with a list.

example  `remplace  2 0 [1;2;3;2;2;9] --> [1; 0; 3; 0; 0; 9]`

```
let listere = [1;2;3;2;2;9];;

let rec remplace n p liste = match liste  with

[] -> []

|a::q -> (if a = n then p else a)::(remplace n p q);;

remplace 2 0 listere;;

- : int list = [1; 0; 3; 0; 0; 9]
```

And there is the problem, i need another funtion to insert the list l1 in the list ?

````
let listerel = [1;2;3;2;2;9];;

let l1 = [-4;-5];;

let rec remplace_par_liste n l1 liste = match liste with

[] -> []

(|a::q -> (if a = n then l1 else a)::(remplace_par_liste n l1 q);;)

remplace_par_liste 2 l1 listerel;;

File "", line 4, characters 113-114:

Error: This expression has type int list
       but an expression was expected of type int```
````

Comment: use `@` to concatenate 2 lists. In `x :: xs`, x has to be an element and not a list

Comment: and use `then l1 else [a]` so both are `int list`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define the second function first.

`::` will let us add `x` to the front of the list created by recursively running the function on the tail of the list.

`@` will let us *concatenate* two lists so we can insert the values in the substitute list into the result.

```
let rec replace_value_with_list v sub lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs when x <> v -> x :: replace_value_with_list v sub xs
  | x::xs -> sub @ replace_value_with_list v sub xs
```

The first function is then much simpler, being just a specialized application of the second, putting that single value into a list.

```
let replace_value v sub lst =
  replace_value_with_list v [sub] lst
```

### Downsides to this implementation

I have decided to edit to mention this based on the comments. The above is not tail-recursive. Each time a function is called, it takes up a certain amount of stack space. The stack is limited. Recursively call a function or functions too many times and you will get a stack overflow error.

OCaml (and some other programming languages, primarily in the functional vein) offer tail-call optimization. If the compiler can determine that the last thing a function does is call itself or another function, then the space the caller occupies on the stack can be reused.

We can modify the existing function from ealier.

> ```
> let rec replace_value_with_list v sub lst =
>  match lst with
>  | [] -> []
>  | x::xs when x <> v -> x :: replace_value_with_list v sub xs
>  | x::xs -> sub @ replace_value_with_list v sub xs
> ```

This operation, for instance, makes the function non-tail-recursive:

> ```
> x :: replace_value_with_list v sub xs
> ```

First we have to call `replace_value_with_list v sub xs` and then add `x` to the front of it. We can solve this issue by passing along an accumulator that builds up the list. We can hide this detail by using a local auxiliary function. Because the local function is taking care of the recursion, `replace_value_with_list` no longer needs to be marked as recursive.

```
let replace_value_with_list v sub lst =
  let rec aux v sub lst acc =
    match lst with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs when x <> v -> aux v sub xs (x :: acc)
    | x::xs -> replace_value_with_list v sub xs (sub @ acc)
  in
  aux v sub lst []
```

Note that when we call the `aux` function, it will build up the accumulator in the reverse order to the way we expect, so we need to reverse the accumulator on the exit condition.

However, this is still not optimal because the `@` operator which performs the concatenation is not tail-recursive. We can overcome this by replacing `@` with `List.rev_append` which is tail-recursive.

```
let replace_value_with_list v sub lst =
  let rec aux v sub lst acc =
    match lst with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs when x <> v -> aux v sub xs (x::acc)
    | x::xs -> aux v sub xs (List.rev_append sub acc)
  in
  aux v sub lst []
```

This process of iterating over a list and accumulating a value is where folds really shine.

```
let rvl v sub lst =
  List.(
    let f acc x = if x <> v then x::acc else rev_append sub acc in
    fold_left f [] lst |> rev
  )
```

Comment: If `sub` is long you might have to reverse it and rev_append to avoid stack overflows due to too deep recursion on `@`.

Comment: Absolutely. I pondered editing to speak to tail recursion, but I tried to keep it simple to match the OP's level of knowledge/experience.

Comment: or reducing it to operations List already has: `let remplacelist v sub lst = List.concat (List.map (fun x -> if x = v then sub else [x]) lst)`

Comment: Final answer: `let remplacelist v sub lst = let sub = List.rev sub in List.fold_left (fun x y -> List.rev_append y x) [] (List.rev_map (fun x -> if x = v then sub else [x]) lst)`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ocaml 4.10 adds tail-recursive function `List.concat_map`. So the solution is even simpler. `let remplacelist v sub lst = List.concat_map (fun i -> if i = v then sub else [i]) lst`.